# MFC ComboBox dropdown list too short

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have dropped `ComboBox` on dialog form. Also I have added some text to it:

```
BOOL CMyAppDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

    CComboBox *combo= (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_TT);
    combo->AddString("s1");
    combo->AddString("s2");

//...
return TRUE;
}
```

When I drop down ComboBox it shows only one selection line and adds arrows to select other items. How to increase dropdown size?

Comment: You are the same person who asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738212/add-strings-to-mfc-combobox), with *the exact same code*. Why have you posted a new question, instead of editing the original?

Comment: Other duplicates: [Combobox not displaying the data items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350189/combobox-not-displaying-the-data-items) and [MFC Combo-Box Control is not showing the full list of items when I click the drop-down menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513263/mfc-combo-box-control-is-not-showing-the-full-list-of-items-when-i-click-the-dro)

Comment: I have done two apps with the same code. One app DDList shows nothing while other shows one position. That is why code is the same. Now I see the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the combo button in dialog editor. You can now drag down to set the open size.